# Decode bitcoin transaction vin address

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm building a graph of blockchain transactions and have a problem to extract source address for a transaction (output addresses are easy,bundled in the getrawtransaction result).
for example this transaction https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/8d787db12e04630a10191772f068fae43d30fbb93e6198e7efa636ce03f16222?show_adv=true
the getrawtransaction has an output of

```
    {
    "result": {
        "txid": "8d787db12e04630a10191772f068fae43d30fbb93e6198e7efa636ce03f16222",
        "hash": "7a0a667bf96d65a11eeab8ec17e232c5afdbe724b6e5e60697790bde3037c2c8",
        "version": 2,
        "size": 248,
        "vsize": 166,
        "weight": 662,
        "locktime": 597359,
        "vin": [
            {
                "txid": "2a1dda8fb17cdcefb26a377492aff6076bd03a93f742d595df1d0ff4951a4305",
                "vout": 0,
                "scriptSig": {
                    "asm": "00140d9cad5ccd91bf6ed56ec6bcb7762ec52ecb7b8d",
                    "hex": "1600140d9cad5ccd91bf6ed56ec6bcb7762ec52ecb7b8d"
                },
                "txinwitness": [
                    "3045022100f2900ede33aab8838464cfb127a962960c29cd97ba62e830c69a38621514d2980220706aa5c28d6e1a134f74b99e6280b357dc1f20ae00f4fcca12ab4ccfab5ceac701",
                    "033b18a261c30edaf859dc523700f3a6085a413ab51b4f63ca84d26073e8e7c709"
                ],
                "sequence": 4294967294
            }
        ],
        "vout": [
            {
                "value": 0.16957303,
                "n": 0,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "asm": "OP_HASH160 d45c146bdb6ad9c61f3300341e2524e8e64394ac OP_EQUAL",
                    "hex": "a914d45c146bdb6ad9c61f3300341e2524e8e64394ac87",
                    "reqSigs": 1,
                    "type": "scripthash",
                    "addresses": [
                        "3M3sV2VBqPXzZHkbdBXo9dMpEw7xxHCFow"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "value": 0.07866618,
                "n": 1,
                "scriptPubKey": {
                    "asm": "OP_HASH160 69f37417a9fb77744ec258ac2ff22e99266ac354 OP_EQUAL",
                    "hex": "a91469f37417a9fb77744ec258ac2ff22e99266ac35487",
                    "reqSigs": 1,
                    "type": "scripthash",
                    "addresses": [
                        "3BMEX8XxUxyEKfRDAJmSMhyd3Y7QWh7PQV"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "hex": "0200000000010105431a95f40f1ddf95d542f7933ad06b07f6af9274376ab2efdc7cb18fda1d2a00000000171600140d9cad5ccd91bf6ed56ec6bcb7762ec52ecb7b8dfeffffff0277bf02010000000017a914d45c146bdb6ad9c61f3300341e2524e8e64394ac87fa0878000000000017a91469f37417a9fb77744ec258ac2ff22e99266ac3548702483045022100f2900ede33aab8838464cfb127a962960c29cd97ba62e830c69a38621514d2980220706aa5c28d6e1a134f74b99e6280b357dc1f20ae00f4fcca12ab4ccfab5ceac70121033b18a261c30edaf859dc523700f3a6085a413ab51b4f63ca84d26073e8e7c7096f1d0900",
        "blockhash": "00000000000000000002726a175241b0f200c561daf30c668d8652cf3b949343",
        "confirmations": 18,
        "time": 1569914555,
        "blocktime": 1569914555
    },
    "error": null,
    "id": null
}
```

the source address per blockchain explorer is 36UuEDoDQX5JppSVnpaccV5DCKiquRyPxB. Was not able to derive it from any of the vin fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode `scriptSig` to get the address.

There is a RPC call in bitcoin core that can help you achieve this: [decodescript](https://bitcoin-rpc.github.io/en/doc/0.17.99/rpc/rawtransactions/decodescript/).